# SharePoint 2013 Permissions & Active Directory Synchronization

Tags: 2013, permissions, active-directory, user-profile-service, groups

I am running into quite an annoying issue with SharePoint & AD Sync.  Basically, SharePoint isn’t recognizing certain users inside the AD groups that I have created and it’s giving them the “Sorry this site is not share with you” message.  Here are a few things I have tried;

- I have run AD synch both incremental and full multiple times and it does not seem to solve the issue.
- I have deleted and re-synchronized the account in question, no resolve.
- I have even added the AD user specifically to the site with “view only” permission and it still does not allow them in.
- I gave the “Everybody” group view only permission and it still does not allow these users in.

I am completely lost as to how to get these people recognized in their AD groups.  Does anyone have any ideas of where else I should look, or something else I should try?  This could potentially be a huge problem, and I’d like to get it rectified as soon as possible.

Comment: By any chance do you have any explicit "deny" policies configured on the web application?  The next step I would take it try to get a look at the claim being issued to the user.  Do a search for "claims viewer web-part" and you will get a few different approaches.

Comment: Are you running any custom code or web parts on the page that might be accessing lists or libraries that they do not have access to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all the responses everyone!  Turns out I had some portions of my SharePoint site not inheriting permissions from the parent.  After correcting this, everyone can log in fine now!

Answer (score 1):

Are you using fqdn's? That is, is the user accessing via "site.company.com", or just "site"? 
You may have some success by ensuring the "site.company.com" or "*.company.com" appears in the intranet zone in Internet Explorer. You may have to restart IE after adding the site to the intranet zone for this to take effect.